# How to create a persistent mounting point in Ubuntu app on Windows-10

Tags: mount, windows-10, network-drive

On my Windows-10 machine, I have a Ubuntu app, which I use for handling files on my local PC. In order to do this, I have two mounting points (one for every harddisk, as you can see):

```
Ubuntu Prompt>mount
...
C: on /mnt/c type drvfs (rw,noatime,uid=1000,gid=1000)
E: on /mnt/e type drvfs (rw,noatime,uid=1000,gid=1000)
```

On my Windows-10 PC, I also have a network drive, as you can see in following `WMIC` result:

```
Windows Prompt>>wmic logicaldisk get Caption, Description
Caption  Description
C:       Local Fixed Disk
...
E:       Local Fixed Disk
H:       Network Connection
...
```

I am capable of mounting the H:-drive as a mounting point (which makes it easily accessible from my Ubuntu app), as you can see:

```
Ubuntu Prompt> sudo mount H: /mnt/h -t drvfs
Ubuntu Prompt> mount
...
C: on /mnt/c type drvfs (rw,noatime,uid=1000,gid=1000)
E: on /mnt/e type drvfs (rw,noatime,uid=1000,gid=1000)
H: on /mnt/h type drvfs (rw,relatime)
```

However, when I close the Ubuntu app and re-open it, the H:-drive related mounting point has disappeared:

```
Ubuntu Prompt> mount
...
C: on /mnt/c type drvfs (rw,noatime,uid=1000,gid=1000)
E: on /mnt/e type drvfs (rw,noatime,uid=1000,gid=1000)

// No H:-drive mounting point anymore!
```

Is there a way I can make this mounting point persistent?
Thanks in advance

**Edit after first reply**

The Ubuntu app I'm using has following specifications (Windows start button, Apps and Features (System settings)):

```
Publisher   : Canonical Group Limited
Version     : 1804.2018.817.0
App         : 0 bytes
Data        : 0 bytes
Total usage : 0 bytes
```

As far as `fstab` is concerned, this is the result of the `find / -name "fstab" 2>/dev/null` command:

```
/etc/fstab
/mnt/c/cygwin/etc/fstab
/mnt/c/cygwin64/etc/fstab
/mnt/c/MinGW/msys/1.0/etc/fstab
/mnt/c/Program Files/Git/etc/fstab
/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual  Studio/2017/Professional/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/TeamFoundation/Team Explorer/Git/etc/fstab
/mnt/c/Users/DominiqueDS/AppData/Local/GitHubDesktop/app-1.1.1/resources/app/git/etc/fstab
/usr/share/doc/mount/examples/fstab
/usr/share/doc/util-linux/examples/fstab
```

I believe the one I need is the first one, but this one currently has following content:

```
Ubuntu prompt> cat fstab
LABEL=cloudimg-rootfs   /        ext4   defaults        0 0
```

This format is so different of the format within the first reply that I'm reluctant to use it (imagine I can't start up my Ubuntu app anymore, due to corrupted mounting points).

Can you confirm me that this is the right `fstab` indeed and that the mentioned format is correct?

Answer (score 12):

I'm assuming you're using WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux) Ubuntu. Then to preserve your mounting points between sessions you need to edit [`fstab`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man5/fstab.5.html) file which is located in `/etc` directory

In your case you should add to your fstab something similar to:

```
H: /mnt/h drvfs defaults 0 0
```

instead of `H:` (your disk name) you can also use your network location `\\server\share\`

Please note, you should be using at least [17093 build of WSL](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/release-notes#build-17093) in order to `fstab` to be processed.

**Note**: Make sure you actually create an empty dir for the mount-point first, e.g. `sudo mkdir /mnt/h`.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, but I'm having some doubts, as mentioned in the edit of my question. Can you confirm that I'm working correctly?

Comment: @Dominique You should indeed use `/etc/fstab` file, and I believe the line `H: /mnt/h drvfs ro defaults 0 0` is correct. In case something goes wrong (but it shouldn't) you can edit fstab file from windows to revert the changes: `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc\LocalState\rootfs`

Comment: I've done the changes, but it seems not to be working: after having restarted the app, the mounting point did not get recreated. By the way, when running `uname -a` I get following result, I believe this means I'm working with build 17134? (`Linux DOMINIQUEDS 4.4.0-17134-Microsoft #523-Microsoft Mon Dec 31 17:49:00 PST 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`)

Comment: @Dominique - there was a mistake in the line I suggested, but I edited my answer, and it should be ok now. Can you please try it? You can mount all entries from fstab with `sudo mount -a` and then check if they're mounted with `mount`

Comment: I confirm it's working, this is the answer I was looking for. (I was on the wrong path trying to modify `/etc/wsl.conf`)

Comment: I'd like to add, of course one must create the `/mnt/h` directory otherwise it silently fails